# Pointers outside the heap

Tags: garbage-collection, ocaml

The OCaml User's Manual version 4.11 states:

> #### 20.2.3  Pointers outside the heap
>
> In earlier versions of OCaml, it was possible to use word-aligned pointers to addresses outside the heap as OCaml values, just by casting the pointer to type value. Starting with OCaml 4.11, this usage is deprecated and will stop being supported in OCaml 5.00.

What does *stop being supported* mean? Performance loss? Warnings? Program crashes?

My app has a lot of constant data. A *lot*.

To help reduce major GC costs, I am considering deep-copying said data out of the OCaml heap to some grow-only/never-collected memory of my own, backed by hugepages. (The data is not constant at compile-time, but once the program is started.)

Does the above imply that my approach will stop working with future OCaml releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs that use out-of-heap pointers (to not well formed OCaml values) crash in the no-naked-pointer mode of the compiler. Multicore OCaml will only support this no-naked pointer mode.

Citing the manual:

> A correct way to manipulate pointers to out-of-heap blocks from OCaml is to store those pointers in OCaml blocks with tag Abstract_tag or Custom_tag, then use the blocks as the OCaml values.

Comment: Good to know. But what about out-of-heap pointers to *well-formed values* which are a deep copy --  all pointers that are recursively reachable from all out-of-heap blocks only point to other well-formed values which are also out-of-heap... IMO these should work, but do they?

Comment: No this does not work either: the GC will follow the out-of-heap pointer and the compactor still thinks that it owns the pointed memory location.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know! One more thing: `Abstract_tag` and `Custom_tag` won't help me either, because code expecting, say, some n-tuple won't "follow" the embedded pointer. These merely communicate to the GC to stop. So I lay my idea to rest and file it under "don't work & won't work", right?

Comment: After some more reading (https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/9610#issuecomment-636922440), it should be possible, but it requires to mark each block header in the third heap as black. Note that what you are trying sounds a lot like the ancient library: https://github.com/UnixJunkie/ocaml-ancient )